# Mouse pointer with text “tooltip” in java

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have to display x,y coordinate values on mouse pointer tooltip. The text should follow the mouse pointer. How can this be done.

From an rcp application, I will click a button, then application will be minimized. Then wherever (on desktop/other application) I move the mouse pointer, it should display some text attached to mouse. I know how to find the coordinates of mouse pointer location, but I want to display those values in mouse pointer tool tip.

Any thoughts.

Comment: why you don't use css?

Comment: Its for rcp application.

Comment: please give more context? where should that happen? in a view? in an editor? all over the rcp? if it is inside a view? what is inside that view? is it a swt canvas? ...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you are asking can't be done in SWT. The only way to do this, and communicate/control it through a Java/Eclipse/SWT app, would be through the Java Native Interface (JNI). You could write a native program (in C++, for example, for a specific OS) to monitor the cursor and change its image as it moves across the screen. You can also pipe data from that native program to your java app. But that is a whole 'nother world beyond Java.

SWT can only manage the cursor over a specific SWT control. Not outside of a SWT control, on the desktop or over another app's windows.

Now, if you could settle for having, say a small dialog/window open (via your application), perhaps tucked in the corner of the screen (rather than at the mouse cursor), that shows the current mouse position that could be done. You'd have to have a process/thread running in the background that would monitor the current screen mouse position, via:

```
display.getCursorLocation();
```

Basically the runnable in the process/thread would simply be in an infinite loop and reading the cursor location, then updating the x,y coords in the "output box."

As an extension to this, you could have a small, bare-bones SWT shell that "follows" the cursor around during the cursor read in the thread. You would simply update the location of the shell based on the current cursor location, and set text in that window (a nested Text control) to the appropriate coordinates. Of course, I don't know how "clean" that would appear, as I haven't tried it. But that's about the best you can do in SWT without JNI.

But in these methods you wouldn't be changing the actual cursor/image.

Hope that helps.